# NextJS 13 Updating Server Component Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So I’m in the process of learning/adapting to NextJS 13 with its new APP folder. I’m having a hard time figuring out how to update data on server components without having to reload the page/app.. Currently my HomePage server component fetches a list of items (events) from MongoDB.   If from behind the scene I change the DB data and then navigate to another route on my app and back to the HomePage without reloading, the new data is not displayed. It’s only displayed if I hard reload the page directly from the browser. The same goes for my EventDetails component. If I change one of the event’s data directly on the database after loading the app in the browser, that change is not displayed in the app when I navigate to that event's detail unless I directly reload the page.

I have set the following option in the fetch function

```
catch: 'no-cache'
next: { revalidate: 1 },
```

And also tried settings this exports in the component file

```
export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

;

But still its not updating the values.

Here is my full code.

```
// HomePage Component (app/page.jsx)
import React from 'react';
import MeetupList from './_components/meetups/meetupList';
export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

const fetchMeetups = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/meetup', {
    catch: 'no-cache',
    next: { revalidate: 1 },
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
};

const HomePage = async () => {
  const meetups = await fetchMeetups();
  return (
    <>
      <MeetupList meetups={meetups} />
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;


//MeetupList.jsx
import MeetupItem from './MeetupItem';

import styles from './MeetupList.module.css';
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

function MeetupList({ meetups }) {
  return (
    <ul className={styles.list}>
      {meetups.map((meetup) => (
        <MeetupItem
          key={meetup._id}
          id={meetup._id}
          image={meetup.image}
          title={meetup.title}
          address={meetup.address}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default MeetupList;
```

Is this something I have to do with the new Server Action which I believe is still in Beta Mode?

Thanks

CES

Comment: It is useless to do `const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/meetup` in your server component as you are already on the server.
So why bothering calling an API route ?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is a long-standing issue in Next 13. Please see the following ticket dating back to Nov 2022 and feel free to upvote.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42991

You can find numerous workarounds in the above thread (some of them no longer work though). Please see which one works best in your case, but here is a workaround I'm using for now:

```js
// components/Link.tsx

"use client";

import { ComponentProps, forwardRef } from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default forwardRef<
  HTMLAnchorElement,
  Omit<ComponentProps<typeof NextLink>, "href"> & {
    href: string;
    refresh?: boolean;
  }
>(function Link({ href, onClick, refresh, children, ...rest }, ref) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return refresh ? (
    <a
      ref={ref}
      href={href}
      onClick={(event) => {
        onClick?.(event);
        if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
          event.preventDefault();
          router.push(href);
          router.refresh();
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  ) : (
    <NextLink ref={ref} href={href} onClick={onClick} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </NextLink>
  );
});
```

```
// test/page.tsx

import Link from "@/components/Link";

<Link refresh href="/">Home</Link>
```

Comment: Hi @IgorDanchenko thanks for the Git Issue Link. Its what I imagined (that its an issue with NextJS 13.4) and now I can confirm it with the link you provided. I did notice that after some "idle time" If a navigate away and back to the home page the data was refreshed. and that's because they added a 30 second "cache" timer to dynamic pages/routes. Apparently there's a request to be able to disable this timer but hasn't been applied yet. Thanks again!

Comment: Keeping my fingers crossed they’ll address this soon-ish :)

Answer (score 0):

[Official Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching) says

> By default, all fetch() requests are cached and deduplicated automatically. This means that if you make the same request twice, the second request will reuse the result from the first request.
>
> Requests are not cached if:
>
> - Dynamic methods (next/headers, export const POST, or similar) are used
>   and the fetch is a POST request (or uses Authorization or cookie
>   headers)
> - fetchCache is configured to skip cache by default
> - revalidate:
>   0 or cache: 'no-store' is configured on individual fetch

So why don't you try something like that

```
const HomePage = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/meetup', { next: { revalidate: 0 } })
  const meetups = res.json()

  return (
    <>
      <MeetupList meetups={meetups} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmet Firat Keler thanks for your quick response. However after doing some tests I came to realize the following:

Catching is enabled in server components by default. When Catching is enabled if I make a change in the database after starting the app in the browser, even if I hard reload the page/app in the browser the data does not change because its "cached" the only way to reload the data is by re-building the app in the server. 

If I disable Catching by doing what you suggested. Then the data changes on each browser reload, but not when navigating to another route and then back.

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler, how does `getInitialProps` work with the new app router? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#old-methods